# If I have a generic class/ interface, is it good practice to define a non-generic base class/interface?

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface

I have a generic interface and I have no functional need for a non-generic version. However, all of the CLR and professional code I've seen has defined a non-generic base interface. Is this for a functional reason, a guideline, or just community habit?

Comment: For the CLR the answer is usually simply that the non-generic versions came first -- .NET 1 didn't have generics. There are interfaces that came later have no non-generic counterparts - `IObservable<T>` is one example. A legitimate use for a non-generic base that's not happenstance is to have a common base type for every `MyGeneric<T>` that's more specific than `object` (mostly for non-generic glue code), and this is not specific to interfaces. You wouldn't declare such a type proactively, though.

Comment: I think it is good practice. Contrary to the accepted answer's claim, I don't think that the following use case is rare at all: A method which does not depend on the actual generic parameter, but executes a common operation on the instances of the generic class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if there is no functional need for it, don't add it.

There is some legacy in the framework classes due to historic reasons. But if you take a look at some newer interfaces like [IReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0) it only have a generic version. Older interfaces like IEnumerable predates the generic version.

There are some situations where a non generic base type is useful, like when you want to treat a bunch of objects with different generic parameters in the same way, but that is a rather specialized use case.